# What is the Cleanup badge awarded for?

Tags: discussion, support

It is written in the '**Badges**' page that the '**Cleanup**' badge is awarded for the "***first rollback***". What does this mean? I could not understand. Can anyone help?

Comment: Someone please pitch in with a good screenshot as @tpg2114 has suggested.

Comment: No love with somebody helping me out... I added screenshots for you.

Comment: On the plus side, now my answer has a revision history that you can click on and see the page, plus the mouseover text about reverting it.

Comment: While @tpg2114 explained it nicely below, I think it might be worth asking why do we have a special badge for this action. I mean, what's the big deal about a _first rollback_? I never really understood that!

Comment: @TheDarkSide I think we have badges that highlight *features* of the platform. It's a way to teach people about the various features there are and how to use them. For instance, if there wasn't a badge, I don't know that Aniket would have ever noticed nor asked about a rollback link. Sometimes a badge can be an incentive to do something tedious (edit a bunch), a reward for participation (gold badges in tags), or a way to introduce users to various bells and whistles of the platform in a more engaging way than telling them to RTFM.

Comment: @tpg2114 - OK. That makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When somebody makes an edit to a post that is bad (wrong, defacing, spam, etc), somebody can come along and "rollback" the version to a previous one. Essentially throw out the edit and go back to a "good" version of the post.

This feature appears under the revision history of a post. You can view the revision history of a post by clicking on the circled link:

[image]

Once you click on that link, you will be shown the revision history for the post. The latest version and a difference of changes is shown. Previous versions include a "rollback" link which allows you to revert to that version. This is circled here:

[image]

It isn't shown here, but the mouse over text for the link says that this will make an older version the current one, undoing all changes newer and this is done to revert an "offensive" post.